# How do I feed the Microsoft Who Bot Information for the "Who knows about ..." query?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I don't quite understand where the Who Bot in MS Teams gets it's information from.
I read that some of it comes from Microsoft Exchange. But I'm particularly interested on how I can feed the bot information about who knows about what in my organization.
How would I go about doing that?

I have found this [thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/whobot-and-data-sources/m-p/172197) on the microsoft tech community, saying that the info for the "who knows about ..." query comes from messages. Does that mean I can not personally add skills to my account or as an admin to other accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information comes Exchange online as stated on [Use Who to find info about people in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-who-to-find-info-about-people-in-teams-3250a8e7-a84d-4256-aa60-ab08ba3d740e):

> Since Who pulls a lot of its information from Exchange Online (your company directory), the more information included in that directory, the smarter Who will be.

These are the information that it can provide information about:

> Who can provide info on who a person reports to, who reports to them, what they know about, and what they've been doing. To get more specific, we've created a complete list of all the questions Who can answer.

Below are the questions it can currently answer:

```
| Question                     | Action                                  |
| ---------------------------- | --------------------------------------- |
| Who is                       | Find someone.                           |
| Who knows about              | Find experts on a topic.                |
| Who works with               | Find someone's collaborators.           |
| Who reports to               | Find someone's direct reports.          |
| Who is the manager of        | Find someone's manager.                 |
| Who has the same manager as  | Find someone's peer group.              |
| Who have I emailed about     | Find people you emailed about a topic.  |
| Who was in the meeting about | Find people you met with about a topic. |
```